Unable to run haunted.js application
Im trying to run locally this starter app:
https://github.com/matthewp/haunted-starter-app

But I dont seem to have any luck.
After running
npm install

Then I want to run the application. But how? How am I supposed to run it? In package.json there are no references to any library to start the browser and run the app.
So what if I try to open the web broser and the file? Well it fails, which makes sense. I got cors issue:
Access to script at 'file://src/index.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, data, http, https, isolated-app.       

I would have expected starter repo should also include stuff to make it run.

That is a template for CodeSandbox and the CORS issue you are countering is because you did not serve the app in your local.
You can install http-server by:
npm install -g http-server

and modify your package.json file:
{
  "name": "haunted-starter-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A project for creating apps with Haunted and lit-html.",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "http-server ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "haunted": "4.5.1",
    "lit-html": "1.1.1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "web-components",
    "lit-html"
  ]
}

and if you type npm start in your terminal and go to http://127.0.0.1:8080 you will serve the app in your localhost.
Steps

First, cloned the project with git clone https://github.com/matthewp/haunted-starter-app.git,
Then, go into directory,
Then, I install dependencies by typing npm install
Then, installed http-server by typing npm install -g http-server,
Then, modified package.json as specified above,
Finally, run the project with npm start


Thanks a lot. In terminal now I can see "Available on:http://127.0.0.1:8080". But I get this error in console: "haunted.js:21 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' (at haunted.js:21:67)". And as instructed I first installed http-server and then run "npm start". Is maybe this code too old (latest commit 5 years ago)?

I have run the code on my local before answering, it worked just fine. Did you also install dependencies by npm install?

Yes I did it again now (npm install). "scripts": {"start": "http-server ."},"dependencies": {"haunted":"4.5.1","http-server": "^14.1.1","lit-html": "1.1.1"}, is how my package.json looks like. I went to http://127.0.0.1:8080/ after "npm start" and Im running on mac, with chrome (if it can make any difference). Still seeing "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' (at haunted.js:21:67)"

I recommend to check my updated answer, remove the project folder and try from scratch by following steps I mentioned. I am also on Mac/Chrome, worked just fine.

This is really crazy. I followed all the steps. But still getting same error. I realized that: 1-I cant run npm install -g http-server with "-g"-flag, cause I get some permission issue. But I guess it doesnt make any difference. Also (maybe doesnt make any difference either) you're saying I should modify package.json AFTER installing http-server(which I also did). But still same strange error.

If you get permission issue you can use sudo npm install -g http-server.

Yes, I tried with sudo and could install that. Unbeliveble, but still getting the same error, sigh.
